# Problems with Server [php-fpm - CPU Overload]

Tags: php-fpm

Since then I have switched the system on php-fpm running it pretty well, have now also pm.children perched on 20. Maybe the pm.children is not high enough? The idle timeout is set to 300.

Nevertheless, I still lags (see screenshot) which just takes away too much computing power and the page begins to Lag

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22035135/zeigen.png.html

What else can I do here? Do not know what's going on.

Comment: What are the specs of the server? What are your current pm settings in FPM 'cat /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf | grep -v "^;" | grep "pm."'

Comment: Specs: AMD X2 240 
8GB RAM / pm.max_children: 20 idletimeout: 300 what else you need?

Comment: pm.start_servers, pm.max_requests, pm.max_spare_servers. Is pm set to dynamic? What version of FPM?

Comment: pm.start_servers is outcommented, pm.max_requests : 500, pm.max_spare_servers is outcommented, pm is setting to ondemand, how to find out the version of FPM?

Comment: "php-fpm -v" or "php -v | grep -i fpm" depending on how it was installed.

Comment: PHP 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Dec 13 2013 01:45:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies